# Python 3.6.x + Windows: Interpreter just shuts down for any external library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Due to external dependencies I need to run python 3.6.x (I know it is EOL) on Windows.
However, any external library causes the interpreter to just silently quit.

As an example I have installed `numpy` in the following way

```py
py -m pip install numpy
```

And then running Python through PowerShell:

```py
PS C:\Users\USER> py
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
PS C:\Users\USER>
```

As soon as I run `import numpy` the python interpreter simply silently returns.
I have tried to install every python 3.6.x available from Pythons official website, and the issue persists.
I fully removed old versions of python between each install.
I cannot find any error logs or anything.
What can be the issue here and how can I debug further?
Any internal library (that I have tried) works

I have tried with the following libraries:

- Numpy
- Tensorflow
- Protobuf
- matplotlib
- scipy
- pandas
- nose
- sympy

Comment: And it works fine for internal libraries?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan yes